# no able to connect mongodb installed on aws ec2 with my windows machine

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, remote-access

configuration done on AWS EC2

mongod.conf

```
net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

security group inbound rule

```
Custom TCP  TCP 27017   0.0.0.0/0   –
Custom TCP  TCP 27017   ::/0    –
```

I am able to access mongodb on aws shell with

```
mongo --host private-ipv4-address
```

but when try to access it remotely on my windows machine I get an error like this

```
Error: couldn't connect to server privateipv4:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error 
connecting to privateipv4:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I have made same changes on my windows mongod.cgf file as on aws ec2 mongod.conf
please help me with this I am new to MongoDB & AWS

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you want to connect with mongo db outside of EC2, you have to use EC2's public IP.

Comment: Thanks for replying @AchyutVyas, I tried this with public IP as well but still not able to connect. getting same error when i use public IP instead of private

Comment: Can you add which EC2 AMI you're using and which MongoDB client you are using on your Windows machine?